# Read OGG as stream of samples for LWJGL 3 OpenAL

Tags: java, audio, lwjgl, openal, ogg

I'm making a game with LWJGL 3, and for the first time I'm learning about the OpenAL library. I'm going to have to include long audio files, and I have decided that OGG will be used for the audio, since music would otherwise take up a lot of space.

What I don't know, though, is anything about how to get the audio data out of the OGG and put them into the OpenAL buffers, which need a `ShortBuffer` of signed short PCM samples.

I've already been trying to look for answers, but everything I find seems to be outdated or irrelevant to my case.

So to summarize: I have OGG files and I need to be able to load them to OpenAL buffers. Also the ability to stream from the files is obviously a must (in this case, read the files one chunk at a time into a double buffer), since music is involved.

Example:

```
ShortBuffer samples = readOggSamplesToBuffer(someInputStream);

int bufferId = AL10.alGenBuffers();
// OpenAL wants the samples as signed short
AL10.alBufferData(bufferId, AL10.AL_FORMAT_MONO16, samples, 44100);
```

Where the function `readOggSamplesToBuffer` would be something like this:

```
private ShortBuffer readOggSamplesToBuffer(InputStream in) {
    // This theoretical class is what I need – something that
    // can read the data from the OGG file.
    OggReader reader = new OggReader(in);

    // Very simplified example
    ShortBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createShortBuffer(reader.getSampleCount());
    buffer.put(reader.samplesAsShortArray());
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Hi Zakru, could you be more explicit about the issue you are having. This question seems too open-ended and could risk being closed. Any code you have at all would be helpful here.

Comment: @RossCradock Added an example of usage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `STBVorbis` class can read Ogg Vorbis files. For streaming you probably want to use

```
STBVorbis.stb_vorbis_open_filename
STBVorbis.stb_vorbis_get_info 
STBVorbis.stb_vorbis_get_samples_short_interleaved
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the library, I completely missed that it exists in LWJGL and didn't have it in my project. I'm just gonna go through the library list to see what other crucial stuff I've missed in my stupidity. :)